# Check if a given string is a isomorphic

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I found this paragraph and I want to implement it in JS:

> For two strings to be isomorphic, all occurrences of a character in
>   string A can be replaced with another character to get string B. The
>   order of the characters must be preserved. There must be one-to-one
>   mapping for every char of string A to every char of string B.
>
> `paper` and `title` would return true. `egg` and `sad` would return
>   false. `dgg` and `add` would return true.

Here's my attempt:

```js
console.log(isIsomorphic("egg", 'add')); // true
console.log(isIsomorphic("paper", 'title')); // true
console.log(isIsomorphic("kick", 'side')); // false

function isIsomorphic(firstString, secondString) {

  // Check if the same lenght. If not, they cannot be isomorphic
  if (firstString.length == secondString.length)
    return false

  var letterMap = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < firstString.length; i++) {
    var letterA = firstString[i],
      letterB = secondString[i];

    // If the letter does not exist, create a map and map it to the value
    // of the second letter
    if (letterMap[letterA] === undefined) {
      letterMap[letterA] = letterB;
    } else if (letterMap[letterA] !== letterB) {
      // Eles if letterA already exists in the map, but it does not map to
      // letterB, that means that A is mapping to more than one letter.
      return false;
    }
  }
  // If after iterating through and conditions are satisfied, return true.
  // They are isomorphic
  return true;
}
```

I'm confused as to why there is an error in it.

Comment: Go through the code in your head. What happens when you do your egg/add? What happens with e? Then with g? Then with the second g?

Comment: So `isIsomorphic("kick", 'side');` should return `true`? Or why do you say there is an error?

Comment: @FelixKling Finally i found the problem.

Comment: what is the question? where exactly are you stuck? you did not say. you mention a mysterious "error" but did not feel the need to elaborate what is it.. where is it...when is it... absolutely nothing. is it a guessing game for us to find that "error" ? Help us help you. provide relevant details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a simple typo:

```
  if (firstString.length == secondString.length) {
    return false
  }
```

You're returning false if the two strings are the same length. Change it to:

```
  if (firstString.length !== secondString.length) {
    return false
  }
```

```js
console.log(isIsomorphic("egg", 'add')); // true
console.log(isIsomorphic("paper", 'title')); // true
console.log(isIsomorphic("kick", 'side')); // false

function isIsomorphic(firstString, secondString) {

  // Check if the same lenght. If not, they cannot be isomorphic
  if (firstString.length !== secondString.length) {
    return false
  }

  var letterMap = {};

  for (var i = 0; i < firstString.length; i++) {
    var letterA = firstString[i],
      letterB = secondString[i];

    // If the letter does not exist, create a map and map it to the value
    // of the second letter
    if (letterMap[letterA] === undefined) {
      letterMap[letterA] = letterB;
    } else if (letterMap[letterA] !== letterB) {
      // Eles if letterA already exists in the map, but it does not map to
      // letterB, that means that A is mapping to more than one letter.
      return false;
    }
  }
  // If after iterating through and conditions are satisfied, return true.
  // They are isomorphic
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah i found it thaaanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is almost correct, ggorlen has shown you the fix. I will, however, give you another solution, which seems to be more elegant to me. Let's introduce the concept of isomorphical signature, which would be a string, which will be similar for all strings which are isomorphic with each other.

Examples:

> paper: 0,2;1;3;4
>
> title: 0;2;1;3;4
>
> egg: 0;1,2
>
> sad: 0;1;2
>
> dgg: 0;1,2
>
> add: 0;1,2

The idea is to show the indexes of letters, in their appearance order. The p in paper is on indexes 0 and 2. The a is on index 1. The e is on index 3. The r is on index 4. Let's implement the `function` which gets the isomorphic signature:

```
function getIsomorphicSignature(input) {
    var helper = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (!helper[input[i]]) helper[input[i]] = [];
        helper[input[i]].push(i);
    }
    var output = [];
    for (var item in helper) output.push(helper[item].join(","));
    return output.join(";");
}
```

Now, if you want to see whether two strings are isomorphic, then you can compare their isomorphic signatures. The elegancy of this solution lies in the fact that you have a storable attribute which says a lot of the string in terms of such comparisons. For instance, if you want to group isomorphic strings into clusters, then you can do something like this:

```
function clusterize(var inputStrings) {
    var output = {};
    for (int i = 0; i < inputStrings.length; i++) {
        var signature = getIsomorphicSignature(inputStrings[i]);
        if (!output[signature]) output[signature] = [];
        output[signature].push(inputStrings[i]);
    }
    return output;
}
```